# Template doesn't know the changement of variable updated in window

Tags: angular

The view can't update the value of `status` variable.

This is an extract of my code deleted the code not relevant:

**component.ts**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   private status: string;

   ngOnInit() {
      this.status = "abc"; // OK binding

      window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = (e) => {
            this.player = new window['YT'].Player('player', {
              videoId: this.video.videoId,
              events: {
                'onStateChange': this.onPlayerStateChange.bind(this)     
              }
            });
        };
    }

    onPlayerStateChange(event) {
       switch (event.data) {
          case window['YT'].PlayerState.PLAYING:
              this.status= "xyz"; //Not possible binding
              break;
}
```

**component.html**

```
<span>{{status}}</span> // it shows only abc, the expected is xyz
```

Anybody has an idea how can I update the variable in the `window` and it reflects on the view?

Comment: did you tried life-cycle hooks

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz with the video example? The `window.onload` example doesn't work because the event is not triggered (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdvpuo)). The window is probably already loaded when the event handler is set.

Comment: The `window.onload` still doesn't work, even with `setTimeout`, because the event handler is not executed. You can test it with a `console.log`.

Comment: So, back to my original question: can you provide a stackblitz for the video case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Completely changing my previous answer because that doesn't seem to be problem in your case

I'm not sure why the property is not updating on the `template` but the value gets changed in the `ts`- may be the `window` function issue i think

After some research i have manual triggered the changes on the `onPlayerStateChange(event)`

Inject `ChangeDetectorRef` in your constructor

`constructor(private dect: ChangeDetectorRef){}`

Add `this.dect.detectChanges();` after you property change - check out the code below

```
onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    switch (event.data) {
      case window['YT'].PlayerState.PLAYING:
          this.name = "yyy";
          this.dect.detectChanges(); //this will manually trigger the changes on your properties
          console.log("I'm playing");
        break;     
    }; 
  }
```

Hope it might work, solution might not be a traditaionl way but you can use this as a workaround - happy coding :)

Comment: No problem - :)

Answer (score 0):

Change: `private status: string;`

to `public status: string;`

Declared variables need to be public for the template to be able to access them. Good explanation here: [Should private variables be accessible in the template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574167/angular2-should-private-variables-be-accessible-in-the-template)

Comment: Moreover, testing the variable change `this.name = 'yyy';`, is better done by a click on a button or on a `setTimeout(() => {
          this.name = 'yyy';
        },0);`

Comment: It should fix it, make sure you are testing the changing of the `status` variable OK. Try using a `setTimeout` instead of within your `onPlayerStateChange(event)` function. If that doesn't work, I recommend setting up a Plunkr, so we can evaluate the full code :)

Comment: Ha, indeed. The setTimeout does actually change the variable in the template: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ktxzzn - So your problem seems to be a scoping issue with the YouTube event..

Comment: Injecting the ChangeDetectorRef like Rahul also implies below will solve it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ktxzzn