# Is this notice "Identifier 'gridOptions' refers to a private member of the componentAngular" telling me that I am not following coding best practices?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid as a framework to build my grids(OBVIOUSLY).
I have followed a simple tutorial. So here's the code so far,

> typography.component.html
>   [image]
>
> typography.component.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {GridOptions} from "ag-grid-community";


@Component({
    selector: 'typography-cmp',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'typography.component.html'
})

export class TypographyComponent {
    private gridOptions: GridOptions;

    constructor() {
        this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
        this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
            {
                headerName: "ID",
                field: "id",
                width: 100
            },
            {
                headerName: "Value",
                field: "value",
                width: 100
            },

        ];
        this.gridOptions.rowData = [
            {id: 5, value: 10},
            {id: 10, value: 15},
            {id: 15, value: 20}
        ]
    }
}
```

This works perfecly. However, as you may have noticed in the html file:

> gridOptions

is underlied in red. 
And this is why:

> Identifier 'gridOptions' refers to a private member of the component

That is understandable. I am following the official tutorial. And I am wondering whether the code breaks any coding rules or best practices?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `gridOptions` in your template, it should not be declared as `private` variable.

More reference on this: [Angular2 - should private variables be accessible in the template?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34574167/1417185)

Another thread is still open on GitHub but you will get some more ideas regarding this: [Better offline compiler error when accessing private properties](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11422)