# How to enable constants imported into component in the template without proxy via properties in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, scope

In my component, I have imported a constant and I'm using it as is.

```
import { NullGuid } from "src/app/models/constants";
...
@Component({ ... })
export class TheComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: SomeService) { this.proxy = NullGuid; }
  ...
  proxy: string = NullGuid;
}
```

In the template, I can reach the service like this.

```
<div>{{this.service.getStuff()}}</div>
```

However, I can't do the same with the constant **unless** it's declared as shown above. Can I somehow expose the imported constant without declaring a proxy property for it?

Comment: No, you can only access public properties on the class from the template.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can access the service injected and that's kind of a property, isn't it? It's a private property, as far I understand and can be accessed by *this.service* **both** in the component **and** in the template. What am I confused about here?

Comment: I believe that will work in JIT mode but fail in AOT; there's no private at runtime. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574167/angular2-should-private-variables-be-accessible-in-the-template. Also you don't have to use this in the template.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah, it's me being sloppy. I forgot to check if  AOT produces errors. My bad. Though, as for the *this* in the template, I noticed that I can't access properties in the service injected as private in constructor if I only use *service.serviceId* but that it worked when I went *this.service.serviceId*. Might be due to the JIT or something and is not a proper approach anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a workaround for that with using pipes. I have a pipe something like below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as constants from "./constants";

type key= keyof typeof constants;

@Pipe({
  name: 'constant'
})
export class ConstantPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args:key): any {
    return constants[args];
  }
}
```

And use it like this :

```
{{null | constant:'LuckyNumber'}}
```

**EDIT:**
As  @KonradViltersen mentioned in the comments i was thinking to use `value` instead of `args`. But then an idea came with the `Angular Language Service`.
If you change `args` type from `string` to type `key` Language service will provide you auto completion which is good when you have large amount of constants. But if you change `value`s type to `key` you will only have some error in your template that will tell you about type mismatch and no runtime errors. It becomes a preference how you use it.

Also problem you are having stands with enums too.

```
import * as enums from './enums';

type key = keyof typeof constants;
type enumKey = (keyof typeof enums) ;


@Pipe({
  name: 'enum'
})
export class EnumPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T extends enumKey, R extends keyof typeof enums[T]>(value: T, args: R): typeof enums[T][R] {
    return enums[value][args];
  }
}
```

Which can be used like

```
{{ 'Complexity' | enum : 'Hard' }}
```

It will provide autocomplete for `Hard` but not for `Complexity`

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c3lu5n-consant-pipe)

Comment: That was nifty. I like that. A question regarding the complexity, though. Wouldn't it make more sense to skip the parameter *args* and only map *value* to whatever that (constant) string value might correspond to? I'm thinking of usage like *{{"LuckyNumber"|constant}}* and then using that specific value to pick from the set of constants imported into the pipe. I figure, since it's a constant, there's no need to provide any (varying) value since it's going to be projected onto the same (constant) value anyway. What do you think? (+1 for niftyness)

Comment: Yes that way it will have clean syntax. I will update it