# Angular string enum as param how to call in the view

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got a string enum and a method in my component:

```
export enum Language {
    de = 'de',
    en = 'en'
}

setLang(lang: Language.en | Language.de) {
    const curent = Language[lang]
}
```

Than I want to call it in the view:

```
<button (click)="setLang('en')">
```

but when I run ng build --prod I've got this error

**Argument of type '"en"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Language'.**

I know if I should call in the component it should be

setLang( Language.en) but

how can I call setLang in the view?

### UPDATE

All in all I don't like very much passing
a reference of my enum to a property class
so may be this could be a better approach

```
type LangKeys = keyof typeof  Language;

function foo(lang:LangKeys) {
    const curent = Language[lang]
}

foo('en')
```

Comment: Since you already accepted an answer i should mention that there  a workaround exists. Which includes creating a pipe. That way you can use enums in views without polluting your component. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447550/12354911)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that:

**Comonent TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export enum Language {
  de = 'de',
  en = 'en'
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  // Store a reference to the enum
  language = Language;

  setLang(lang: Language) {
    const current = Language[lang];
    console.log(current);
  }

}
```

**HTML file**

```
<button (click)="setLang(language.en)">click</button>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Just create a property in your Component Class:

```
import { Language } from './path-to-enum-file';

...

languageEnum = Language

setLang(lang: Language.en | Language.de) {
  const curent = Language[lang]
}
```

And then in the template try doing this:

```
<button (click)="setLang(languageEnum.en)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Expose the enum as a property of your component:

```
current: Language;
Language = Language;

setLang(language: Language) {
  this.current = language;
}
```

and in the view:

```
(click)="setLang(Language.en)"
```

Alternative: use a union type rather than en enum:

```
type Language = 'en' | 'de';
[...]
current: Language;

setLang(language: Language) {
  this.current = language;
}
```

and in the view:

```
(click)="setLang('en')"
```